# Marcar checkbox como marcados a la hora de actualizar

Tags: php, html, sql-server

Tengo un formulario que a la hora de editar aparece los datos de que se ingresaron en automatico en caso de querer actualizarlos excepto que no aparecen los checkbox marcados que se ingresaron me gustaria saber ¿Como le hago?

**(En donde dice **inventario** son los checkbox que se insertaron)**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**(Este es el formulario para editar)**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**(Este es el codigo)**

```
    <?php include '../includes/db.php';

?>


<div id="entradas<?php echo $row['folio']?>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
       

<div class="modal-dialog"> 
               <div class="modal-content modal-md"> 
                  <div class="modal-header"> 
                     <center><h4 class="modal-title" id='head'>
                     Editar orden de entrada
                     </h4> </center>
                     <div id="retCode"></div>
                  </div> 
                       <form method="POST" id='update_entradas'  action="../forms/update_forms.php?action=entradas" > 
 <div class="modal-body">
   
    <div class="form-horizontal">

    
          <div class="form-group" id="form-login">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Inventario:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ANTENA">ANTENA <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ESPEJO LATERAL">ESPEJO LATERAL <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="EMBLEMAS">EMBLEMAS <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TAPONES RUEDAS(4)">TAPONES RUEDAS(4) <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="MOLDURAS">MOLDURAS COMPLETAS<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TAPÓN DE GASOLINA">TAPÓN DE GASOLINA<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="LLANTA DE REFACCIÓN">LLANATA DE REFACCIÓN<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="RADIO/TIPO">RADIO/TIPO<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ENCENDEDOR">ENCENDEDOR<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TAPETES">TAPETES<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="BOCINA DE CLAXÓN">BOCINA DE CLAXON<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="GOLPES EN CARROCERÍA">GOLPES EN CARROCERÍA<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="EXTINTOR">EXTINTOR<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TARJETA DE GASOLINA">TARJETA DE GASOLINA<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="GATO">GATO<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="LLAVE DE RUEDAS">LLAVE DE RUEDAS<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ESTUCHE DE HERRAMIENTAS">ESTUCHE DE HERRAMIENTAS<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TRIÁNGULOS DE SEGURIDAD">TRIÁNGULOS DE SEGURIDAD<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="CERTIFICADO DE VERIFICACIÓN">CERTIFICADO DE VERIFICACIÓN<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TARJETA DE CIRCULACIÓN">TARJETA DE CIRCULACIÓN<br>  
            </div>
          </div>  

          <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="btn_sub"><i class="fa fa-save "></i> Actualizar</button>
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-close"></i>Cerrar</button>
            </form>
                     </div>
                     </div> 
            </div>
          </div>
```

**(El ejemplo de lo que busco)**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**(Código de donde se jala la información para el formulario)**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial scale=1'>
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
<!--Get your own code at fontawesome.com-->

</head>

<?php 
//activamos almacenamiento en el buffer
ob_start();
require 'header.php'; 

 ?>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">

      <!-- Default box -->
<div class="col-md-13">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
        </div> 
        <div class="panel-body"> 
        <div class="col-md-13">
    <h3>Ordenes de Entrada</h3>
    
      
      <a class=" btn btn-md btn-info"  href="#ordenes" data-toggle="modal"><center><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Nueva Orden de Entrada</center></a>

<br>
<hr style="border-bottom:2px solid black"></hr>
</div>  

       <table id="entrada" class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr id="heads">
        <th class="col-md-1 text-center"></th>
        <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Folio</th>
        <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Nombre</th> 
        <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Dirección</th>
        <th class="col-md-1 text-center">VIN </th>
        <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Teléfono</th> 
        <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Marca</th>
        <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Modelo </th>
        <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Año</th> 
        <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Kilometraje</th>
        <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Placas</th>
        <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Color </th>
        <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Inventario</th> 
        <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Comentarios</th>
        <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Fecha</th>
        
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    
    include '../includes/db.php';
    
      $query=  mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT  * FROM orden_entrada");
         
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {   
  
    ?>
      <tr>


      <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" a href="#entradas<?php echo $row['folio']?>" data-toggle="modal" a title="Editar">
    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>   
    </td>

        <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['folio']  ?></td>
        <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['nombre'] ?></td>
        <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['direccion'] ?></td>
          <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['VIN'] ?></td>
        <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['telefono'] ?></td>
        <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['marca'] ?></td> 
        <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['modelo']   ?></td>
        <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['año'] ?></td>
        <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['kilometraje'] ?></td>
          <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['placas'] ?></td>
        <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['color'] ?></td>
        <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['inventario'] ?></td>
        <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['comentarios'] ?></td>
        <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['fecha'] ?></td>
       </tr>
       
      <?php 
   include '../includes/entrada_update.php';

    };
      ?>  
    </tbody>
  </table>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**En esta parte del código se jala la información para el formulario de editar aqui es donde se encuentra la base de datos**

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que de la consulta te traes los valores del inventario, tal y como lo extraes.

```
$res = 'ANTENA, ESPEJO LATERAL, EMBLEMAS, TAPONES RUEDAS(4), MOLDURAS, TAPÓN DE GASOLINA, LLANTA DE REFACCIÓN, RADIO/TIPO, ENCENDEDOR, BOCINA DE CLAXÓN, EXTINTOR, GATO';
```

Y en tu html tienes el div form

```
<div class="form-group" id="form-login">
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Inventario:</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ANTENA">ANTENA <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ESPEJO LATERAL">ESPEJO LATERAL <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="EMBLEMAS">EMBLEMAS <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TAPONES RUEDAS(4)">TAPONES RUEDAS(4) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="MOLDURAS">MOLDURAS COMPLETAS<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TAPÓN DE GASOLINA">TAPÓN DE GASOLINA<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="LLANTA DE REFACCIÓN">LLANATA DE REFACCIÓN<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="RADIO/TIPO">RADIO/TIPO<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ENCENDEDOR">ENCENDEDOR<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TAPETES">TAPETES<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="BOCINA DE CLAXÓN">BOCINA DE CLAXON<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="GOLPES EN CARROCERÍA">GOLPES EN CARROCERÍA<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="EXTINTOR">EXTINTOR<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TARJETA DE GASOLINA">TARJETA DE GASOLINA<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="GATO">GATO<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="LLAVE DE RUEDAS">LLAVE DE RUEDAS<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ESTUCHE DE HERRAMIENTAS">ESTUCHE DE HERRAMIENTAS<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TRIÁNGULOS DE SEGURIDAD">TRIÁNGULOS DE SEGURIDAD<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="CERTIFICADO DE VERIFICACIÓN">CERTIFICADO DE VERIFICACIÓN<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TARJETA DE CIRCULACIÓN">TARJETA DE CIRCULACIÓN<br>
</div>
```

Usando javascript

```js
const resPHP = '<?=$res?>';    
const resArray = resPHP.split(", ");
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'); 
 checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
  if (resArray.includes(checkbox.value)) { 
     checkbox.setAttribute('checked', true);
   }
});
```

Si por el contrario solo deseas usar PHP usa esta funcion

```
function checked($value) {
global $res;
if (strpos($res, $value) !== false) {
  echo 'checked'; } }
```

y en tu html

```
<div class="form-group" id="form-login">
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Inventario:</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ANTENA" <?=checked('ANTENA')?>>ANTENA <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ESPEJO LATERAL" <?=checked('ESPEJO LATERAL')?>>ESPEJO LATERAL <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="EMBLEMAS" <?=checked('EMBLEMAS')?>>EMBLEMAS <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TAPONES RUEDAS(4)" <?=checked('TAPONES RUEDAS(4)')?>>TAPONES RUEDAS(4) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="MOLDURAS" <?=checked('MOLDURAS')?>>MOLDURAS COMPLETAS<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TAPÓN DE GASOLINA" <?=checked('TAPÓN DE GASOLINA')?>>TAPÓN DE GASOLINA<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="LLANTA DE REFACCIÓN" <?=checked('LLANTA DE REFACCIÓN')?>>LLANATA DE REFACCIÓN<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="RADIO/TIPO" <?=checked('RADIO/TIPO')?>>RADIO/TIPO<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ENCENDEDOR" <?=checked('ENCENDEDOR')?>>ENCENDEDOR<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TAPETES" <?=checked('TAPETES')?>>TAPETES<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="BOCINA DE CLAXÓN" <?=checked('BOCINA DE CLAXON')?>>BOCINA DE CLAXON<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="GOLPES EN CARROCERÍA" <?=checked('GOLPES EN CARROCERÍA')?>>GOLPES EN CARROCERÍA<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="EXTINTOR" <?=checked('EXTINTOR')?>>EXTINTOR<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TARJETA DE GASOLINA" <?=checked('TARJETA DE GASOLINA')?>>TARJETA DE GASOLINA<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="GATO" <?=checked('GATO')?>>GATO<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="LLAVE DE RUEDAS" <?=checked('LLAVE DE RUEDAS')?>>LLAVE DE RUEDAS<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ESTUCHE DE HERRAMIENTAS" <?=checked('ESTUCHE DE HERRAMIENTAS')?>>ESTUCHE DE HERRAMIENTAS<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TRIÁNGULOS DE SEGURIDAD" <?=checked('TRIÁNGULOS DE SEGURIDAD')?>>TRIÁNGULOS DE SEGURIDAD<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="CERTIFICADO DE VERIFICACIÓN" <?=checked('CERTIFICADO DE VERIFICACIÓN')?>>CERTIFICADO DE VERIFICACIÓN<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="TARJETA DE CIRCULACIÓN" <?=checked('TARJETA DE CIRCULACIÓN')?>>TARJETA DE CIRCULACIÓN<br>
</div>
```

Saludos espero te sirva de ayuda

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por ayudarme una pregunta para agregar el codigo ya sea de JAVASCRIPT o PHP tengo que abrir otro documento o en que parte de ese mismo documento puedo agregarlo?

Comment: Es mejor si lo haces por Javascript, es más rápido. Todo en la misma página.

Comment: Ya actualice mi codigo ese es el que tengo en toda esa pagina y por alguna razon me marca error entonces no sabria donde colocar el codigo que me proporcionaste

Comment: Postea todo el código de tu página y te indico dónde colocarlo

Comment: listo ya lo actualice todo completo

Comment: Creo no me hago entender. Haber, de dónde sale la información para llenar el modal? Yo imagino que de una consulta. En la primera imagen logro ver la base de datos y la data que en teoría traes de vuelta para mostrar en el modal. Esa es la información que necesito

Comment: Ah okay okay listo ya lo agregue tambien

Comment: De verdad ya me liaste con tantos fragmentos de paginas. la variable que yo llamo **$res = $row['inventario'];** luego aplicas la funcion **checked** que te hice y la llamas en el modal **<input type="checkbox" name="inventario[]" value="ANTENA" <?=checked('ANTENA')?>>ANTENA <br>**